# Cannot connect to Informix DB using python

Tags: python-3.x, informix

I have tried many ways to connect to IBM Informix DB using python code *(`pyodbc`, `IfxPy`, `pymssql`, `ibm_db`, `ibm_db_sa`)* but so far I have no luck and I am getting the below-mentioned errors:

## 1

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import ibm_db, ibm_db_dbi

conn_str='database=database_name;hostname=host;port=16827;protocol=tcp/ip;uid=username;PWD=password'
ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str,'','')
conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(ibm_db_conn)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select id, name from employee")
rows=cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Error:

```
----> 4 ibm_db_conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str,'','')
      5 conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(ibm_db_conn)
      6 

 SQLCODE=-1013on: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "" could not be found.  SQLSTATE=42705
```

## 2

```
CONNECTION_STRING = 'DRIVER={%s};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;HOST=%s' % (DRIVER, SERVER, DATABASE, USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST)
con = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING, autocommit=False)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from employee")
rows=cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Error:

```
----> 3 con = pyodbc.connect(constr, autocommit=False)
      4 cur = conn.cursor()
      5 cur.execute("select * from employee")

OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

## 3

```
engine = create_engine("ibm_db_sa://informix:informix@host:16827/database_name")

for row in engine.connect().execute('select * from employee'):
    print(row)
```

Error:

```
---> 32 from sqlalchemy.connectors.zxJDBC import ZxJDBCConnector
     33 from .base import _SelectLastRowIDMixin, DB2Dialect, DB2ExecutionContext, DB2Compiler
     34 from . import reflection as ibm_reflection

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.connectors.zxJDBC'
```

## 4

```
# Using SQLAlchemy 
import pyodbc
engine1 = create_engine("pyodbc+ibm_db://informix:informix@host:16827/database_name")

for row in engine1.connect().execute('select * from employee'):
    print(row)
```

Error:

```
NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:pyodbc.ibm_db
```

## 5

```
import IfxPy
ConStr = "SERVER=lo_informix1410;DATABASE=database_name;HOST=host;SERVICE=16827;uid=username;PWD=password;"
conn=IfxPy.connect(ConStr,"","")
```

Error:

```
----> 1 import IfxPy
      2 ConStr = "SERVER=lo_informix1410;DATABASE=database_name;HOST=host;SERVICE=16827;uid=username;PWD=password;"
      3 conn=IfxPy.connect(ConStr,"","")

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing IfxPy: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can someone please suggest how to connect to IBM Informix DB for running queries using python both in Windows & Linux environments?

Thanks

Comment: To use DRDA (as implemented with ibm_db module), the informix server must be configured to listen for DRDA connections on a specific port. To use SQLI, use module IfxPy instead of ibm_db. The Informix client SDK must be installed already and configured.  This Ifxpy module must first be installed (via pip, or conda, according to how your python is managed) and then configured (e.g. INFORMIXDIR etc). For pyodbc, verify odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini contents are correct, and isql (on linux) and odbcad32.exe (on windows) can connect to the dsn correctly.

Comment: Removing the DB2 tag, This is for Informix only.

Comment: @mao, so the requirement is that we want a robust rest service using which we can connect to any IBM Informix DB from Windows and Linux environments. Keeping that in mind I feel, using "Ifxpy" is comparatively the easiest. For this can you please provide me with some links/documentation to work with it? If there is a better and easier alternative, please do suggest ... thanks.

Comment: There is not a single source of documentation for all the required components, as far as I know. Instead use IBM supplied product docs, pyodbc docs, unixodbc docx, ifxpy docs etc.  Grunt work needed.  This is configuration not programming.

Comment: You are trying different drivers and some of those are not suitable for an Informix databases (like the SQL Server one).
I suggest to go with the IfxPy one. The error you are getting there is because the module fails to load the native libraries (like iclit09b.so/iclit09b.dll)  which need to be in the PATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH. There should be some info in the IfxPy project page.

If you use the first one

Comment: Check the issues in IfxPy project page. Depending on the Python version you may need some extra stuff (like https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/issues/35) to ensure the Informix libraries can be loaded.

Comment: Hi, I took your advice @Mao and #jsagrera and using IfxPy, in the official documentation also it is mentioned as [https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy] we don't need to install any SDK's specifically at least that's how it is working for at the moment for 3.0.5 Version onwards. And I am able to query the Informix db successfully in windows env. However in Linux it still does not work so I had installed Informix SDK(ibm.csdk.4.50.FC6.LNX.tar), yet getting the same error despite defining LD_LIBRARY_PATH ==> `ImportError: libthcli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @jsagrera currently I am using IfxPy, in the official documentation it is mentioned as [github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy] we don't need to install any SDK's specifically at least that's how it is working for at the moment for 3.0.5 Version onwards. And I am able to query the Informix db successfully in windows env. However in Linux it still does not work so I had installed Informix SDK(ibm.csdk.4.50.FC6.LNX.tar), yet getting the same error despite defining LD_LIBRARY_PATH ==>` ImportError: libthcli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory `.

Comment: During the install, if the setup.py can't find the Informix libraries, it will attempt to download the 'OneDB-Win64-ODBC-Driver.xxx') distribution (which contains the native libraries needed to connect to Informix. Same stuff you get with Informix CSDK.

There was a 'recent' change on Python which it does not longer look for libraries in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Maybe that's the problem you are seeing.   Do you have $INFORMIXDIR/lib and $INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @jsagrera, yes I do.
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/projadmin/ibm_informix_sdk/lib:/home/projadmin/ibm_informix_sdk/lib/esql:/home/projadmin/ibm_informix_sdk/lib/cli`

While I was going through the documentation again I see we need SDK 4.10.

Official Doc: *FYI: Informix Client SDK 4.10 xC2 or above is needed for the driver to make connection to the database. Make sure Informix Client SDK is installed and its environments are set prior to running application.*
I have installed 4.50 so it should be working already, not sure whats going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to build IfxPy from scratch

```
informix@irk:/tmp$ mkdir test

informix@irk:/tmp$ cd test

informix@irk:/tmp/test$ python3 -V      

Python 3.10.1

informix@irk:/tmp/test$ export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix/IBM/4.50.FC5

informix@irk:/tmp/test$ export CSDK_HOME=$INFORMIXDIR

informix@irk:/tmp/test$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli

informix@irk:/tmp/test$ git clone https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy.git
Cloning into 'IfxPy'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2189, done.
...
...
Resolving deltas: 100% (1623/1623), done.

informix@irk:/tmp/test$ cd IfxPy/IfxPy

informix@irk:/tmp/test/IfxPy/IfxPy$ python3 setup.py bdist_wheel  --plat-name manylinux1_x86_64
Detected 64-bit Python
Smart Triggers are enabled.
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
copying IfxPyDbi.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.10
running build_ext
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DHAVE_SMARTTRIGGER -I/tmp/test/IfxPy/IfxPy -I/tmp/test/IfxPy/IfxPy/Include -I/opt/informix/IBM/4.50.FC5/incl/cli -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c ifxpyc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/ifxpyc.o
ifxpyc.c: In function 'estrndup':
ifxpyc.c:158:13: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
....
....
running install
running install_lib
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
creating IfxPy.egg-info
writing manifest file 'IfxPy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: no files found matching '*.pyd'
writing manifest file 'IfxPy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying IfxPy.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/IfxPy-3.0.5-py3.10.egg-info
running install_scripts
informix@irk:/tmp/test/IfxPy/IfxPy$ 

informix@irk:/tmp/test/IfxPy/IfxPy$ sudo pip3 install ./dist/IfxPy-3.0.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl --force-reinstall
Processing ./dist/IfxPy-3.0.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: IfxPy
  Attempting uninstall: IfxPy
    Found existing installation: IfxPy 3.0.5
    Uninstalling IfxPy-3.0.5:
      Successfully uninstalled IfxPy-3.0.5
Successfully installed IfxPy-3.0.5
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
informix@irk:/tmp/test/IfxPy/IfxPy$ 


informix@irk:/tmp/test/IfxPy/IfxPy$ cd /tmp

informix@irk:/tmp$ cat test.py 
import IfxPy

ConStr="Driver={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER};SERVER=ol_informix1410_1;DATABASE=sysmaster;host=irk;service=13808;protocol=onsoctcp"

conn=IfxPy.connect(ConStr,"informix","whocares")
if conn:
      stmt = IfxPy.exec_immediate(conn, "SELECT tabname FROM systables")
      res = IfxPy.fetch_tuple(stmt)
      rows = res[0]
      print (rows)

informix@irk:/tmp$ python3 test.py 
systables
```

If I remove the cli directory from LD_LIBRARY_PATH I get the same error complaining about not finding libthcli.so

```
informix@irk:/tmp$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql
informix@irk:/tmp$ python3 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import IfxPy
ImportError: libthcli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
informix@irk:/tmp$ 

informix@irk:/tmp$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli
informix@irk:/tmp$ 
informix@irk:/tmp$ python3 test.py 
systables
informix@irk:/tmp$ 
informix@irk:/tmp$
```

Can you get a strace and check where is search for the library?
Something like:

```
informix@irk:/tmp$ strace -o trace.txt python3 test.py 
systables
informix@irk:/tmp$ grep libthcli.so trace.txt 
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/informix/IBM/4.50.FC5/lib/libthcli.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/informix/IBM/4.50.FC5/lib/esql/libthcli.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/opt/informix/IBM/4.50.FC5/lib/cli/libthcli.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
informix@irk:/tmp$
```

Another test you can try is adding the lib directories to the system path

```
informix@irk:/tmp$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ifx.conf 
/opt/informix/IBM/4.50.FC5/lib
/opt/informix/IBM/4.50.FC5/lib/esql
/opt/informix/IBM/4.50.FC5/lib/cli

informix@irk:/tmp$ sudo ldconfig

informix@irk:/tmp$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH

informix@irk:/tmp$ python3 test.py 
systables

informix@irk:/tmp$
```

Comment: please allow me a few hours, as soon as I get back, I will check the steps mentioned by you at once and accept the solution. :)
*Appreciate your support*