# ibm_db.connect string stating error with database name

Tags: python, pandas, etl, informix

I'm running python on a server that will eventually do my ETL and one of the databases that I have to connect to is running Informix (I believe its version 14).  I have access to the Informix DB and have an active ODBC connection on a Windows 10 machine that connects no problem.  I'm trying to get the basic connection down to the Informix Server and keep getting the following error:

```
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "" could not be found.  SQLSTATE=42705 SQLCODE=-1013
```

My code to connect:

```
import ibm_db
import pandas as pd

conn_str = ibm_db.connect('database=mydatabase;host=myservername;port=9088;protocol=onsoctcp;uid=myusername;pwd=mypassword','','')

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM schema.table', conn_str)

print(df)
```

With the error, I know the name is correct and I've tried a few different variations on the DB name as I know that its case sensitive with informix.  I've also tried connecting to some of the configuration databases that are available in the drop down from the ODBC connection and everything matches up.  I've also tried running it in a virtual environment and treating the server as a strictly python server.  OS is Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to connect to the standard informix port.
To use ibm_db you have to define drda connection.
Example from my sqlhosts:
onlinedr | drsoctcp | drhost | 9099

Comment: Is there a better package to use for Python that ibm_db that would connect using the standard informix port?  I've tried ifxPy after downloading the Informix SDK but for whatever reason it will not compile correctly from my machine even with the INFORMIXDIR and LD_LIBRARY_PATH declared.  Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with linux ODBC setup.

Comment: ifxPy (https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy) is the native one. 
There are some precompile (wheels) modules so may not need to compile it. 
But compiling it from source on Linux should work fine. What errors where you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the IfxPy install again and had an error showing a missing files/sources and an error on the use_2to3 file that was giving me issue.  I managed to get it installed once I found this post: ([Cannot connect to Informix DB using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220967/cannot-connect-to-informix-db-using-python)) which shows one other thing that has to be declared than the GitHub page for IfxPy.

```
export CSDK_HOME=$INFORMIXDIR
```

Once I followed that and declared it on my system it compiled no problem and I've been able to extract some data.  I'm still playing with it but I'm at least getting data out, now I just have to get it in a useable format.  Appreciate all the help.